# Laravel saving foreign key in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

What is the best approach to save the stream_id as a foreign key inside the junk table
I already created the tables both tables.

Migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('junk', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('stream_id')->after('id')->unsigned();
    });
}
```

Controller function:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    // create junk, junk shall contain the stream id as a foreign key (save in database)
    $junk = new Junk();

    // stream information data -> the data is saved correctly here
    $data = $request->all();
    $stream = new Stream();
    $stream->fill($data);

    if($stream->save())
    {
        return redirect()->route('stream.new')->with('success', 'saved.');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->route('stream.new')->with('error', 'not saved.')->withInput();
    }
}
```

My Junk Model:

```
public function junk()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Stream', 'junk_id');
}
```

My Stream Model

```
public function stream()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Junk', 'stream_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use foreign key contraints? If so, You might take this approach. Here is an example of a location table that has a foreign key to the coordinates:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();

    Schema::create('location', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->uuid('id');
        $table->primary('id');   
        $table->uuid('coordinate_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('state')->nullable();
        $table->string('zipcode')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('location', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->foreign('coordinate_id')->references('id')->on('coordinate');
    });
}
```

There is no reference to the location on the coordinate table.

You should not be assigning $data = $request->all(); you should be using Validator class to protect yourself from mass assignment issues.

It would also be nice to see your Junk class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the functions to relacionate the models, you can make this:

```
$junk = new Junk();
$junk->stream()->associate($request->all());
```

In the relationship:

- One to Many, uses the `associate()` method
- Many To Many, uses the `attach()` method

For more information about the relations in Laravel (Eloquent ORM)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Comment: Did not work I added my model to the quesiton mind having a look

Comment: If the relationship is One To One, the methods are `hasOne()`